# MySQL query to get one of each Item

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with php and MySQL, I am making a messaging app, the app has communicates with a remote database, in my database is my messaging table, the table has 9 tables of which includes the "Subject table", I need help, I want to make a query that retrieves only one subject of each type, lets say I have 10 messages with the subject "Man", 12 of the "Dog", I want it to get only one man and one dog below is a graphic representation of my Messaging Table.

```
| message_id | subject     | username     |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          |      cyber  |     Chrome   | 
| 2          |     Hyper   |     Ciare    |
| 4          |      Cyber  |     Gorger   |
```

Comment: `select distinct( subject ) from mytable`

Comment: `in my database is my messaging table, the table has 9 tables of which includes the "Subject table"`. Either your database is a real life [Inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/) or your question is not very clear. How about you share some data and your desire/expected outcome

Comment: its got 9 but the table is an illustration, all I need is an overview not the exact answer, I wanna think on my own, not spoon fed so I had to just give an illustration.

Comment: I am not so good at explaining, there happens a situation like on message id 1 and 4 where two messages have the same subject, but instead of getting the same subject twice, I want to get it once and from it, I can use to get all messages with the same subject, so I wanted a query to get each subject only once, so when it gets everywhere else where it will find it, it will leave it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL's [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp):

> SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM table

This will fetch each subject only one time, even if it appers more than once.

Comment: but how can I get the username with the distinct subject?

Comment: If you want the user name, why is the subject relevant?

Comment: I mean, how can I get the username and the distinct "subject" at the same time, how to get the entire row.

Comment: you can use GROUP BY, but that will only give you the first user name, for example, from the table in your question, adjacent to Cyber you will get Chrome. For example: SELECT subject, username FROM table GROUP BY subject